# Why my url_regex can't filter mp4 file in squid.conf?

Tags: squid

I'm studying squid for proxy admin. Recently, I need filter the access of multimedia files from squid proxy. So I write this in my squid.conf --

```
acl test_network src 100.70.224.0/23
http_access allow test_network

#acl media_url url_regex -i .*\.mp4$ .*\.mkv$ .*\.webm$
acl media_url url_regex -i ^http://.*\.mp4$
http_access deny media_url test_network
```

But unfortunately, I found it can't work, the test result is --

```
vsa10995083:/tmp/eisen # curl -x "100.70.225.235:8080" -O "http://100.70.224.70/kitty_in_the_sun.mp4"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 36.3M  100 36.3M    0     0  1508k      0  0:00:24  0:00:24 --:--:-- 1558k
```

I tries -- `.mp4$ ,  .*\(?*)mp4$` ...   All failed that curl test always can download that mp4 file.
I don't know what's wrong in my squid.conf. Please kind help on it.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh.
After test, find the answer -- it's due to the "http_access allow test_network" before the "http_access deny media_url test_network"
So it's allowed first and override the "deny" rules.
Then if the squid.conf like this --

```
acl test_network src 100.70.224.0/23

acl media_url url_regex -i \.mp4$ \.mkv$ \.webm$
http_access deny media_url test_network

http_access allow test_network
```

Then everything is OK.